# How to create a temporary table that's local to the connection, without being forced to use a simple explicit create table statement?

Tags: .net, scope, sql-server-2012, temp-tables, sqlcommand

I want to create a temporary table that's local to the SqlConnection, using a statement of the form "select into #tempTable", because I do not have to specify column names and types, as I would with a "create table #tempTable" statement;

I want the temp table to be visible from subsequent SqlCommands running on the same already-open SqlConnection, and only on that connection.  I don't want to use global temporary tables, because I don't want to have to deal with name conflicts when the query is run concurrently.

I discovered a local temp table is visible to subsequent SqlCommands only if it's created with a simple, lone "create table #tempTable" statement with no SQL parameters.  On the other hand, if it's created with a "select into" statement with parameters (or strung together with other statements in a single SqlCommand), then that causes the whole thing to be executed in a procedure, which limits the scope of the temp table to that procedure.

In general, it seems impossible to use temp tables across SqlCommands when those SqlCommands are anything other than simple "create table" statements with no parameters, because of how the SqlCommand works internally.

Creating the temp table separately would work (i.e. a simple "create table #tempTable (col type, col type, etc.)" statement with no SQL parameters), but that involves explicitly specifying all the column types (which is too much maintenance, IMO), whereas with a "select into" statement, I don't have to specify the column types because they're matched to the source columns automatically.

I want a temporary table created with "select into" to persist as long as the connection is open.  Is there a way to scope the table to the open connection?

As it stands now, it's really unpredictable behavior, because depending on how the SqlCommand is constructed, it may or may not wrap itself in a stored procedure, so a temporary table created within a SqlCommand may or may not be visible to subsequent SqlCommands run on that same open connection.

Comment: Not a 100% sure I understand what you mean by "executed in a procedure" but if you need multiple connections to access a temporary table, why not use a global temp table?  SELECT INTO ##globalTemp

Comment: Because a global temp table would cause name conflicts with every other instance of the command running at the same time.

Comment: This is within a stored proc or dynamic sql?  I get the feeling its dynamic, which means you can tokenize the sql and share a unique table name.

Comment: It's with an SqlCommand object in .NET.  It's sort of a black box, in the sense that I don't know whether it's issuing statements directly, or running them as dynamic SQL.  I get the feeling that the answer is "it depends on the sql query text", and that's the problem.  I need a way to ensure a table is scoped to the open connection, rather than a particular procedure (+child procedures).

Comment: It's doesn't use multiple connections, it uses multiple SqlCommand objects on the same, already-open SqlConnection.  The problem is that "new SqlCommand( "create table #tempTable" ), will be visible in subsequent SqlCommands, but one like "new SqlCommand("select * into #tempTable from X; select * from #tempTable;")" will result in the statement being executed in a procedure (as dynamic SQL?) such that it's dropped at the end and not visible to subsequenct SqlCommands on that same connection.  It entirely depends on what the text looks like that's passed to SqlCommand when the table is created.

Comment: So last attempt at helping, then I will tuck tails and run, but if you are doing a select into and select from in command objects then that is dynamic sql and the current scope of that one connection will keep that temp table and if you reuse that sqlconnection object for other commands and not dispose/close of it then they should have access to that open resource.  If you are opening other connections, even if the conn string is the same it wont be able to access that table across conns without being global.  If it really is dynamic just pass in a variable name for a shared global table.

Comment: I don't close or reopen the connection at all between SqlCommands.  I create an SqlConnection instance, open it once, and I pass it to two consecutive SqlCommands, without modifying it.  I know for certain that a temp table created with a simple "create table #tempTable" statement will persist to subsquence SqlCommands, whereas one created with "select * into #tempTable; select * from #tempTable" will not persist to subsequent SqlCommands.

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out in the comments, you are coding your SQL in the C# as C# strings.  Thus you can create a temp table with any name you want.

I'll leave the implementation details up to you, but this fragment should get you on your way:

```
public function DoSomeSqlStuff() {
    var tempTableName = CreateTempTableName();
    using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString) {
        using SqlCommand firstCommand = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE #" + tempTablename + "column definitions here", connection) {
            firstCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using SqlCommand secondCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM #" + tempTableName, connection) {
            secondCommand.ExecuteReader();
        }

        using SqlCommand thirdCommand = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE #" + tempTableName, connection) {
            thirdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

certainly a simplistic example - but should get you set on the right path.

As for connection-scoped temp tables as a feature provided by the database... I've never heard of such a thing.  Doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: For that to work, those would have to be global temp tables, so I'm assuming you meant to have two "##" hash tags.  That being the case, they'd have to be guaranteed to be unique, so I'd have to use a GUID identifier, which still does not guarantee uniqueness, even if it does in practice.  The only problem with this approach is that it would generate unique query strings with unique table names, which could prevent caching of the command string in SQL server, causing an unnecessary performance hit.   I ended up just biting the bullet and issuing the explicit "create table" statement for now.

Comment: Ran out of character in last comment.... thank you for the answer.  This is basically what such a solution would look like.  I'm not ever sure SQL Server caches query strings so they don't have to be parsed every time, but it is a rather long query string I'm issuing, so not having to use unique table names could boost performance.

Comment: Just to further the discussion - you only need "guaranteed uniqueness" for the duration of any particular connection lifetime.  You stated you are only issuing 2 commands against a connection.  If we're generous and say each query takes 1 minute to run - you only need each table name to be unique for 2 minutes at a time.  GUID is overkill for this - but very easy to use.  Depending on the frequency that connections are being made, `Random.Next` might be "good enough", though I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: A GUID (or something equivalently unique) would absolutely be necessary in order to use a global temp table name without risking a conflict.  The "duration of any particular connection lifetime" is 100% of the time.  From the time any connection is open to the time that connection is closed, you would have a name conflict if even a single other connection opened concurrently and tried to run the same query.  So guaranteed uniqueness of the names is required 100% of the time, regardless of the connections duration.  Random.Next is insufficient.  You'd need Interlocked.Increment on a static var.

Comment: @Triynko : the scope of temp table is per connection